# Give and solve a recurrence

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The exercise is;

> There are *m* functions from a one-element set to the set {1, 2, …, *m*}.
>   How many functions are there from a two-element set to {1, 2, …, *m*}?
>   From a three-element set? Give a recurrence for the number of *T(n)* of
>   functions from an *n*-element set to {1, 2, …, *m*}. Solve the recurrence.

I've gotten to the point that I "know" there are $m^n$ options to the function $$f:\{1,...,n\}\to \{1,...,m\}$$. How do I set up a recurrence relation and solve it?

I've gotten this far;
$$
T(0) = 1 \\
T(1) = m \\
T(n) = T(n - 1) \cdot m
$$

Solving it;
$$
T(n) = (T(n - 2) \cdot m) \cdot m \\
     = ((T(n - 3) \cdot m) \cdot m) \cdot m \\
     = T(n - n) \cdot m^n \\
     = 1 \cdot m^n = m^n
$$

But I'm unsure whether I've even done the correct thing?

Comment: Looks good.  As you say, it seems unnecessary but as an exercise in recursion writing it looks fine.